# How to check if Swift string contains only certain characters?

Tags: swift, string, special-characters, contains

I have a string and I want to check if it only contains the the 26 alphabetical characters, in upper and lower case, and the 10 number characters:

```
abcdefghijklmnopkrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789
```

How can I check that a string does not contain any special characters?

Comment: `if string.range(of: "^[a-zA-Z0-9]*$", options: .regularExpression) != nil`

Comment: Hint: `CharacterSet`

Comment: Thank you very much to everyone for your help. It works perfectly.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Next time you post any question, Please mention what you have tried and what is an issue with code.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use

`if string.range(of: "^[a-zA-Z0-9]*$", options: .regularExpression) != nil` as mentioned by @sulthan.

1. `^` is the starting point of regex. This does not match any
   character. For example, ^P is regex matching letter P at the
   beginning of the String
2. `*` Regex followed by  * will handle repetition in a regex. For
       example P* Matches PPP or P. This will matches the empty string also.
3. `$` is the end of the string. This does not match any
   character. For example, P$ regex will match P at the end of the string.

Use `+` instead of `*` if you want to avoid empty string. `"^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$"` as mentioned by [vadian](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5044042/vadian)

Comment: The pattern matches also an empty string. If you want to check additionally if the string is **not** empty use the pattern `"^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$"`